# Using unicode chars ratio and colon in unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math

How to tweak unicode-math so that u+003A colon behaves like AMS's \colon, and u+2236 like a relation symbol (potentially assuming amsmath is loaded)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `\colon` to use U+2236 and make U+003A math active, defined to yield `\colon`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\AtBeginDocument
 {
  \char_set_active_eq:nN { `: } \colon
  \mathcode`:="8000
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\patchcmd{\colon}{:}{∶}{}{}% first is U+003A, second is U+2236

\begin{document}

$f:A\to B$ % U+003A

$f∶f$      % U+2236

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beautifully simple, thanks! It seems to fail with Asana-math, though, any idea why?

Comment: @TomHirschowitz [Works for me (see picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhZ6x.png).